# Chunking data in Angular and outputting into separate rows

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with chunking out some data in my controller then outputting it correctly in my view.

I have (eg) 50 sets of information.

```
1.     name: Chris
       rank: 1
       location: Australia

2.     name: Sarah
       rank: 13
       location: UK
```

etc etc.

I am chunking it like this:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

So:

$scope.information = chunk(information, 4);

I have a `<div class="row">` and then have 4 `column divs within that` and I want to display all the information splitting it into 4 columns per row.

I am trying to do this:

```
<div class="row services" ng-repeat="rows in information">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item scrollimation fade-up" ng-repeat="item in rows">
    <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I'm new to AngJS. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

edit: console.log of the information array.
This is basically what it looks like. A bit different schema but its the same idea.

```
 Array[1]0: Array[3]0: Object$$hashKey: "object:6"datetime: "14/01/2015"id: "dc995b0f486868a4"location: "Australia"rank: "Legendary Eagle Master"steamname: "KriiV"__proto__: Object1: Object$$hashKey: "object:7"datetime: "2015-02-19T11:20:06.427Z"id: "cbd1cbb908a9a9c3"location: "Australia"rank: "Silver III"steamname: "http://steamcommunity.com/id/asdf"__proto__: Object2: Object$$hashKey: "object:8"datetime: "2015-02-19T11:25:55.099Z"id: "7796ac966f129897"location: "United Kingdom"rank: "Silver IV"steamname: "http://steamcommunity.com/id/asdfasd"__proto__: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qun0Ex?p=preview Just get properties from item. See demo http://embed.plnkr.co/Qun0Ex/preview Is that your issue?

Comment: @PSL But how do I make sure I get 4 items per row?

Comment: You are doing it right. It has 4 items per row. WHat is the issue? Did you see my demo?

Comment: @PSL Oops yes sorry I didn't see the first ng-repeat